# How to select Distinct rows from the Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I am trying to select the distinct rows from the database using the code given below. When i run this query it does not return the result what i am expected. I need distinct city names into dropdown control.

```
using (var context = new CountryEntities())
        {
            var city = (from u in context.Cities
                        where u.StateId == StateID
                        select new
                        {
                            cityId = u.CityId,
                            cityName = u.CityName

                        }).Distinct();


            cboCity.DataSource = city.ToList();
            cboCity.DataValueField = "CityId";
            cboCity.DataTextField = "CityName";
            cboCity.DataBind();
            cboCity.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        }
```

My database table is

[image]

What should i do. Please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there multiple cities with the same `Name` but a different `ID`?

Comment: Yes multiple cities and multiple stateId in the table.

Comment: So which CityId do you use if you have two cities with the same name? That's the real question.

Comment: Within the same state, though, are there cities with the same name?

Comment: No actually i am storing Pincode also. So there may be multiple cities with the same pincode.

Answer (score 2):

If you must ensure that there are no duplicate city names, you can do it like this:

```
var city = context.Cities
    .Where(u => u.StateId == StateID)
    .GroupBy(u => u.CityName)
    .Select(g => new {
        cityId = g.First().CityId,
        cityName = g.Key
    });
```

However, this has the consequence of throwing away some cities with duplicate names, because only one `cityId` is going to get used.

If you wish to overcome this limitation, you would need to introduce another column for disambiguation of the city - say, a area name or a postal code. Then you would need to change the code to append this disambiguation marker to names of cities that cannot be uniquely identified by their name alone.